# Developing for Blackberry tablet without AIR

Tags: blackberry, qnx

BlackBerry Tablet OS is basically a handicapped QNX so can I somehow develop apps for the tablet as a usual QNX application, by using gcc and PhAB for photon gui?

How do I develop apps for the Blackberry tablet without use of Adobe AIR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to AIR, you can use [RIM's WebWorks SDK](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/).  RIM has also announced "upcoming" [support for native (C/C++), Android and JavaME apps on the PlayBook](http://press.rim.com/release.jsp?id=4935).  They have even [demoed the use of Android apps](http://crackberry.com/new-demo-video-showing-android-app-player-blackberry-playbook) just a few days ago at [BlackBerry World](http://www.blackberryworld.com/).